# DataGrid not appropriate dataProvider value

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, air, arraycollection, dataprovider

I have an ArrayCollection filled with 'o' objects. This AC should be the dataProvider of a DataGrid. After setting the dp: `dgMT.dataProvider=acDataGrid` the DataGrid contains only the last item of the arrayCollection.
Code:

```
[Bindable]
        public var acDataGrid:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        protected function ddlLanguage_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void{

            gcTranslate.headerText=Globals.acLanguages.getItemAt(ddlLanguage.selectedIndex,0).toString();
            Globals.acActValues=convertXmlToArrayCollection(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("xmls"+File.separator+Globals.acFileNames.getItemAt(ddlLanguage.selectedIndex,0)));

            Globals.acDataGrid.removeAll();
            var o:DataGridObject = new DataGridObject();
            var i:int=0;
            var angol:Object;
            for each(angol in Globals.acValues){
                o.en=angol.value;
                o.name=angol.name;

                if(i<Globals.acActValues.length && o.name==Globals.acActValues.getItemAt(i,0).name){
                    o.translation=Globals.acActValues.getItemAt(i,0).value;                 

                }
                else{
                    o.translation="";
                    Globals.acActValues.addItemAt("",i);
                }

                acDataGrid.addItemAt(o,i);

                trace("NAME: "+acDataGrid.getItemAt(i,0).name+" VAL:"+acDataGrid.getItemAt(i,0).en+"TRANS: "+acDataGrid.getItemAt(i,0).translation);
// the values are different!
                i++;
            }
            dgMT.dataProvider=acDataGrid;//setting the dataProvider         

        }
```

How could I reach that the DataGrid's rows are filled with the correct values?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating `o` just once, outside of the `for` loop. Which means your just changing the values of that instance's properties and adding that same instance to the dataprovider over and over. You should instead create a new instance on every iteration.

To fix this, simply move the instantiation of `o` inside the `for` loop:

```
for each(angol in Globals.acValues){
    var o:DataGridObject = new DataGridObject();
    ...
}
```